# PyTorch - ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, pytorch

I've trained Retinanet for object detection in google colab and now I want to load its `.pt` file in another python project but I keep getting this error. Any thoughts?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\stefan_cepa995\Desktop\breast-mammography-app\app.py", line 522, in <module>
    model = torch.load(os.path.join(".", "models", "retinanet", "retinanet_gwd.pt"))
  File "C:\Users\stefan_cepa995\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 594, in load
    return _load(opened_zipfile, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
  File "C:\Users\stefan_cepa995\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 853, in _load
    result = unpickler.load()
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'retinanet'
```

Comment: can you share the code, its bit unclear from the errors only.

Comment: how are you saving your model? did you save the state_dicts only or did you use the whole module ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Rika mentioned in comments, solution is to save `state_dict` and then load it with `load_state_dict()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps though:

```
pip install . --user
```

check by `pip list` and see if `keras-retinanet` is an installed module.
if not then install it.

```
pip install keras-retinanet
```

Comment: Same issue. Bare in mind that I am using PyTorch.